# Apache: Server the same document root from multiple ports

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

Consider the following apache `site` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    SSLEngine on
    ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory ...>
       ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This specific VirtualHost serves content in SSL on port 9000. I would like it to serve the exact same contents on a few different port - say, `9000-9005` and `9010`.

Is there a serve the content from multiple ports without duplicating the `VirtualHost` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Source : [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/219261/declaring-multiple-ports-for-the-same-virtualhosts)